# CSS is not displayed in Selenium WebDriver

Tags: java, jsf-2, selenium-webdriver

I have a really strange error. I wrote a JSF-webpage. The page functions as expected if I test it manually in Firefox. But, if I try to test the site with Selenium(FireFoxDriver), the site looses its CSS-files after first clicking on a link. If I refresh the site and the cache with Cmd+F5, the CSS-files appear again in this Firefox window.
I have no clue, where the problem comes from. Has anybody already been confronted with this problem or any ideas?

Comment: Maybe double check the URL you are navigating too. Also check your Firefox security settings. Does sound strange.

Comment: Are you using the same FireFox profile when running the under automation vs manually?  You could pause the automation when it is running to check if things are being blocked or enable to load when running with Selenium.

Comment: I've confronted this problem before when trying to interact with Grooveshark. My solution was to force a refresh, as you suggest.

Comment: I've tried to use `driver.navigate().refresh()`, but it has no real effect. The test works well and the css-file is rendered correctly up to the end of the test. If I click manually on the same link in the Firefox window created by Selenium, the page is rendered without the stylesheet.

Comment: Is their a easy way to get my normal Firefox-profile into the test or is this the best way: [http://girliemangalo.wordpress.com/2009/02/05/creating-firefox-profile-for-your-selenium-rc-tests/]?

Comment: I had this issue; I switched from using LiveServerTestCase to StaticLiveServerTestCase and that fixed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happened to me as well. Although I do not know why exactly it is happening, It disappeared when I switched to chromedriver 26.0.1383.0

https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver

I don't want this to sound like an advert for Google chrome, but I did notice a significant increase in speed while running my test suite on chrome rather than firefox.

If you are determined to use firefox or do not want to switch i would try disabling caching by:

1-Create a new profile with firefox.exe -ProfileManager

2-Go to the Firefox profile directory and add the following to prefs.js:

```
user_pref("browser.cache.disk.enable", false);
user_pref("browser.cache.memory.enable", false);
user_pref("browser.cache.offline.enable", false);
user_pref("network.http.use-cache", false);
```

then tell selenium to use this profile

```
ProfilesIni allProfiles = new ProfilesIni();
FirefoxProfile profile = allProfiles.getProfile("Selenium");
FirefoxDriver browser = new FirefoxDriver(profile);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the good explanation! I used the solution for FireFox and it works!

Answer (score 4):

Had the same problem, fixed it this way.

```
public static void initialise(){
    FirefoxProfile newProfile = new FirefoxProfile();
    newProfile.setPreference("browser.cache.disk.enable", false);
    Instance = new FirefoxDriver(newProfile);           
}
```